# Text Disappears After Creation using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, text, drawing

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I'm just trying to add some text, and I have no idea why but for the last maybe 30min, after I create them, they just disappear. I have tried other draw features (lines, polygons), restarting my map, trying different mxd's, restarting ArcMap and even restarting my computer.

I am using the 'Drawing' toolbar.

I am in Data View.

Comment: Are you changing between Layout and Data Views?  If so, which one are you using to add the text?

Comment: I am not changing views, I am in data view.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. What are the properties of your text? do you still see the rectangle around the text when you select with a box around the position of your text? Sometimes, deleting the normal.mxt file helps.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by properties of my text, but its just arial font, 10 pt size. I see the rectangle and I'm able to type it in, but once i click out of it to move it, it disappears

Comment: Try right clicking the rectangle, select order, then bring to front

Comment: theres no rectangle to click, once I stop typing, it disappears

Comment: did you set a reference scale ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are adding text to a map in the data view it will be added as annotation. There's a difference between text (on a layout, like a title) and text in the data view (actually an annotation). The data frame has a default annotation group. The only way I can recreate the described problem is by adding text from the drawing toolbar when the default annotation group is turned off.

As a possible fix, go to your dataframe in the table of contents, right click and select properties:

[image]

Then in the properties dialog box choose the annotation groups tab and make sure the default annotation group is checked and click okay. Your text should appear:

[image]